# executing setTimeout function before the time if socket has received some request

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I have a use case where I am executing the setTimeout function after 20 seconds but I want that function to be executed if socket connection from front end has returned something before 20 seconds. and I don't want it to run after 20 seconds in that case. how can I achieve this.

Comment: Please show us some code so we can work out what is wrong and give suggestions or help you fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest scheme here is to just put your code in a function that you use with `setTimeout()` and, if the timer is still running, you cancel the timer and call the function directly:

```
function doSomeTask() {
    // code here for your task
}

// schedule task to run in 20 seconds
// remember timer handle so we know it's running
let timer = setTimeout(() => {
    timer = null;
    doSomeTask();
}, 20*1000);

// elsewhere in your code where you want to call your function
// earlier than the timer (if it hasn't already been called)
if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = null;
    doSomeTask();
}
```

---

Promises can offer some benefit here because they already make sure that a given promise is only ever resolved or rejected once and that can be taken advantage of here.  To use them elegantly, I'd probably create a little state object that makes it really simple to use.

```
function delayExecute(fn, t) {
    let obj = {state: "timer"};
    let p = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        obj.runNow = resolve;
        obj.cancel = reject;
        setTimeout(resolve, t);
    }).catch(err => {
        obj.state = "err";
        throw err;
    }).then(() => {
        fn();
        obj.state = "done";
    });
    return obj;
}

function doSomeTask() {
    // code here for your task
}

let task = delayExecute(doSomeTask, 20*1000);

// then some time later, to run it sooner (if it hasn't already run)
// calling the .runNow() method after the function has already run will do nothing
task.runNow();
```

This same interface could be built without promises too.  I just thought I'd show how to leverage some of the one-way state transitions of promises for this purpose.

Comment: Definitely the most straightforward way. Promises are overkill for this particular issue, in my opinion. +1

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - I added a promise-based implementation too just to show how it could be done cleanly also.  Promises certainly aren't required here, but they do some useful things which can be used here.

Comment: Nice update, but your `cancel()` doesn't actually cancel :P Oh, wait, I derped. That's a strange approach, I would have done that a little different personally, but it does indeed work.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts - `.cancel()` rejects the promise which means the promise can never get to its `.then()` handler so it never calls `fn()`.  It does cancel.  Also prevents any future `.runNow()` method calls from doing anything.  I didn't bother to stop the timer if that's what you were looking for.  When the timer fires, it calls `resolve()` which does nothing for a promise that is already resolved or rejected. Just trying to leverage the one-way state transitions of promises to get some functionality for free.

Comment: Yeah, I caught that. It took me a second to remember that the `resolve()` in that case would do nothing, that's where the disconnect was.

Answer (score 0):

You have few options to do that. Since you didn't include any code or info on how you're managing concurrency then I'll show you one way that seems reasonable using promises.

```
let resolve;
let promise = new Promise(res => resolve = res);

// function to call after max 2s or after response
let fn = () => {
  console.log(process.uptime(), 'Function called');
};

// the timeout:
setTimeout(resolve, 1000);

// the fake response handler:
setTimeout(() => {
  console.log(process.uptime(), 'Request returned');
  resolve();
}, 2000 * Math.random());

promise.then(fn);
```

The `then` handler will be run only once. Execute this program multiple times and you'll see that the function is called just after the fake response handler is called if it is called before the 1 second timeout fires, or immediately after the timeout if the timeout is first.